# How do I use rsync with an IPv6 address via SSH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsync, ipv6

I've been having difficulty with connecting to my IPv6 address via rsync. Because the argument for the destination folder is colon-separated, the IPv6 address disrupts this like so:

`root@fdff::ffff:ffff:ffff:/path/to/dest`

How do I use rsync with an IPv6 address via SSH?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll want to wrap the address in brackets like so:

```
rsync -rtlzv -e ssh /path/to/src 'root@[fdff::ffff:ffff:ffff]':/path/to/dest
```

Comment: Note this doesn't work when using OpenSSH directly, the feature request was rejected https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1602

Answer (score 15):

Try placing the IPv6 address in brackets, like this:

```
root@[2001:db8:1234:5678:feed:face:dead:beef]:/path
```

Answer (score 6):

I've run into the same issue and found out that the accepted answer did not work with my version of rsync (2.6.9) when using *user@* as prefix

As a workaround you can use the `-l user` option of ssh:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -l root' /path/to/src '[fdff::ffff:ffff:ffff]:/path/to/dest'
```

Comment: That version has got to be more than 10 years old. Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: It's the default shipped with macOS 10.11

Comment: Thank you! I had this problem on OSX myself (10.12). Works perfectly, none of the other answers work.

Comment: MacOS 12.6.2 is still on `rsync 2.6.9`